# Add right click menus to nautilus without nautilus-actions

Tags: ubuntu-one, nautilus, menu, mime-type

I want to know how I can add action when the user right-clicks on specific MIME-types or folders **without** the use of nautilus-actions.

I would be happy if this was possible using Nautilus Scripts as well, but I want them to show up only at specific mime types.

I believe it is possible: Ubuntu One does it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Nautilus extension API for that. In particular I recommend [Nautilus-Python](http://projects.gnome.org/nautilus-python/).

Here's a simple example that adds a context menu item for MIME type `text/plain`:

```
from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject

class ExampleMenuProvider(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.MenuProvider):
    def activate(self, menu, files):
        print 'activated' # do something

    def get_file_items(self, window, files):
        if len(files) != 1 or files[0].get_mime_type() != 'text/plain': return
        item = Nautilus.MenuItem(
            name='SimpleMenuExtension::Do_Something', label='Do Something')
        item.connect('activate', self.activate, files)
        return [item]
```

You'll need to install `python-nautilus` and `gir1.2-gconf-2.0` packages and place the above Python script in `~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/`.

Comment: thanks! That is very useful! Is there something for C/C++ ? On your link says something about C but...

Comment: @hakermania: There is a C API documented in http://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/